# Zip - How do you exclude files from a zip using a database black-list?

Tags: shell, zip, tar

I know that `tar` has the option to exclude files to be included in a new archive using a black list database (e.g. exclude.db).

```
tar -czf --exclude-from="exclude.db" archive.tar.gz /home/user/directory/
```

Where the exclude.db file looks like this:

```
exclude1.txt
exclude2.jpg
exclude3.db
```

How would you do this when using `zip`?

Zip has the option of excluding files, but as far as I see, you can't do this using a list in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Zip 3.0 and Ubuntu:

```
zip -r -x@exclude.db archive.zip /home/user/directory/
```

Example `exclude.db`, if the files are located in subdirectories:

```
*/exclude1.txt
*/exclude2.jpg
*/exclude3.db
```

Comment: OK thanks.
Can you omit the "* /" in the exclude.db file? That the database can contains only pure names?

Comment: According to my tests, `*/` is necessary if the files are located in subdirectories. Maybe someone will find another solution.